# Creating an offset line with the rgeos package

Tags: r, geos, rgeos

I discovered the [`ST_OffsetCurve`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_OffsetCurve.html) function in PostGIS, it is based on GEOS.

[image]

I'd like to compute the same in the R software, using the package `rgeos`. I couldn't find a same-named function though.

Has anybody an idea if there is a similar function in `rgeos` or any other GIS package?

Comment: There is currently no wrapper for the `GEOSOffsetCurve_r` function in the rgeos package (I started to implement this feature, but it is not ready for submission yet).

Comment: Mhh, do you know of any alternative? Let's say I sample the line with `spsample` from the `sp` package and get 10 points on the initial line, and now I want to get the "cousin" point, but with an offset of x meters (rectangular to the line). Actually I don't even want to "copy" a line but sampled points on a line. I would have cloned the line and sampled its clone, if there would be an OffsetCurve function.

Comment: Just a Python alternative, the `shapely` module (also `geos` based) has a `parallel_offset` method

Comment: Well, it should be in R. But I might call Python code from within R as far as I can remember. Vice versa was possible once. We'll see. But is there at least an (unstable) development version of `rgeos` that I could clone? Or a function that you already coded and I could integrate? At least something? ;-)